# Alternate training between two datasets

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to use augmented and not augmented datasets in each epoch(for example: augmented in one epoch not augmented in a different epoch) but I couldn't figure out how to do it. My approach was loading DataLoader in each epoch again and again but I think it's wrong. Because when I print indexes in `__getitem__` in my `Dataset` class, there is a lot of duplicates indices.

Here is my code for training:

```py
for i in range(epoch):

    train_loss = 0.0
    valid_loss = 0.0
    since = time.time()
    scheduler.step(i)
    lr = scheduler.get_lr()

    #######################################################
    #Training Data
    #######################################################

    model_test.train()
    k = 1
    tx=""
    lx=""
    random_ = random.randint(0,1)
    print("QPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPPQPQ")
    print(random_)
    print("QPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPPQPQ")
    if random_== 0:
            tx = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                #  torchvision.transforms.Resize((128,128)),
                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])

            lx = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                    #  torchvision.transforms.Resize((128,128)),
                    torchvision.transforms.Grayscale(),
                    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                    # torchvision.transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.cat([x, 1 - x], dim=0))
                ])
    else:
            tx = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                #  torchvision.transforms.Resize((128,128)),
                
                torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop(96),
                torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation((-10, 10)),
                # torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                torchvision.transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
            ])
            lx = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                    #  torchvision.transforms.Resize((128,128)),
                    
                    torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop(96),
                    torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation((-10, 10)),
                    torchvision.transforms.Grayscale(),
                    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                    # torchvision.transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.cat([x, 1 - x], dim=0))
                ])
    Training_Data = Images_Dataset_folder(t_data,
                                      l_data,tx,lx)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Training_Data, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler,
                                           num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,)

    valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Training_Data, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler,
                                           num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,)

    
    for x,y in train_loader:

        x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
       
        #If want to get the input images with their Augmentation - To check the data flowing in net
        input_images(x, y, i, n_iter, k)

       # grid_img = torchvision.utils.make_grid(x)
        #writer1.add_image('images', grid_img, 0)

       # grid_lab = torchvision.utils.make_grid(y)

        opt.zero_grad()

        y_pred = model_test(x)
        lossT = calc_loss(y_pred, y)     # Dice_loss Used

        train_loss += lossT.item() * x.size(0)
        lossT.backward()
      #  plot_grad_flow(model_test.named_parameters(), n_iter)
        opt.step()
        x_size = lossT.item() * x.size(0)
        k = 2
```

Here is my code for the dataset:

```py
    def __init__(self, images_dir, labels_dir, transformI=None, 
        transformM=None):
        self.images = sorted(os.listdir(images_dir))
        self.labels = sorted(os.listdir(labels_dir))
        self.images_dir = images_dir
        self.labels_dir = labels_dir
        self.transformI = transformI
        self.transformM = transformM
        self.tx=self.transformI
        self.lx=self.transformM

        

    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
      
        with open("/content/x.txt", "a") as o:
            o.write(str(i)+"\n")
        i1 = Image.open(self.images_dir + self.images[i])
        l1 = Image.open(self.labels_dir + self.labels[i])

        seed = np.random.randint(0, 2 ** 32)  # make a seed with numpy generator

        # apply this seed to img tranfsorms
        random.seed(seed)
        torch.manual_seed(seed)
        
        img = self.tx(i1) 

        # apply this seed to target/label tranfsorms
        random.seed(seed)
        torch.manual_seed(seed)
        label = self.lx(l1)

        return img, label
```

How can i achieve what i want?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code embedded *here*.

Comment: @Ivan Done sir. can you check it out now please?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do: do you want to alternate between an augmented dataset and unaugmented dataset every epoch?

Comment: @Ivan yes exactly.

Comment: @Ivan in one epoch it will select augmented images in another it will select not augmented images. (images=mask and image (image segmentation))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating a dataset and data loader for each epoch doesn't seem to be the way to go. Instead, you may want to instantiate two sets of dataset + data loader, each one with its corresponding augmentation pipeline.

Here is an example to give you a basic frame:

Start by defining the transformation pipelines inside of the dataset itself:

```
class Images_Dataset_folder(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images_dir, labels_dir, augment=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.tx, self.lx = self._augmentations() if augment else self._no_augmentations()

    def __len__(self):
        pass
        
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        pass

    def _augmentations(self):
        tx = T.Compose([
            T.ToTensor(),
            T.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])

        lx = T.Compose([
            T.Grayscale(),
            T.ToTensor()])

        return tx, lx
        
    def _no_augmentations(self):
        tx = T.Compose([
                T.CenterCrop(96),
                T.RandomRotation((-10, 10)),
                T.ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
                T.ToTensor(),
                T.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])

        lx = T.Compose([
            T.CenterCrop(96),
            T.RandomRotation((-10, 10)),
            T.Grayscale(),
            T.ToTensor()])

        return tx, lx
```

Then you can construct your training loop as:

```
# augmented images dataset
aug_trainset = Images_Dataset_folder(t_data, l_data, augment=True)
aug_dataloader= DataLoader(aug_trainset, batch_size=batch_size)

# unaugmented images dataset
unaug_trainset = Images_Dataset_folder(t_data, l_data, augment=False)
unaug_dataloader = DataLoader(unaug_trainset, batch_size=batch_size)

# on each epoch you go through the
for i in range(epochs//2):
    # call train loop on augmented data loader
    train(model, aug_dataloader)

    # call train loop with un-augmented data loader
    train(model, unaug_dataloader )
```

---

This being said, you will essentially loop over the dataset twice: once on unaugmented images and a second time around with augmented images.

If you want to only iterate only once, then the easiest solution I can come up with is having a random flag inside the `__getitem__` that would decide whether or not the current image needs to get augmented.

---

*Side note: you wouldn't want to use train data in your validation set!*

Comment: No worries @canovichh. Consider accepting the answer as valid (by clicking on the green checkmark on the left) if you found this solved your question!

Comment: so sir, I am sure that your way is the correct way to do so but when I instantiate the dataset in each loop I am getting the correct output. Why it would be a way to go? Performance issues(performance of the system) ?

Comment: The reason is it's often preferred to not instantiate classes this way but instead do it once and then use it via its own function interface. This has performance implications, yes.